# Command-shift-D equivalent for Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I'm trying out the Xcode 4 beta, and I'm really missing ⌘-Shift-D, which lets you search for symbols or files and open them quickly. Does anyone know how to invoke it in Xcode 4?

Comment: Isn't Xcode 4 still under NDA ?

Comment: Uhoh, does that mean I shouldn't be asking questions like this? The beta is available to all iOS developers...

Comment: That's correct, you shouldn't. Under NDA means under NDA. You cannot discuss it with anyone who is not covered under the same NDA. The appropriate forum for a question like this is the [Apple Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/).

Comment: in theory you could lose your Apple developer status for breaking the terms of an NDA, but that probably only happens in extreme cases.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>

Comment: Although honestly I use this so much that I prefer Command+T (same as text edit).  You can remap tab functionality to Command+Shift+T but I find that I use "Open Quickly" far more often

Answer (score 1):

Command-Shift-O is the new "open quickly" keyboard shortcut in XCode 4.  "O" for open I guess...

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 3 you can command-doubleclick a symbol to jump to its definition. A future version of Xcode which is under NDA may provide very similar functionality.